# Block the forced EU browser selection dialog

Tags: windows, internet-explorer, windows-update

If you have missed it, sometime in March 2010, if you live in the EU and happen to like to use Internet Explorer an update will be installed onto your computer from Windows Update that will FORCE you to actively select if you want to continue to use Internet Explorer or select among 12 other browsers.

[Read this article by Microsoft for more information](http://www.microsoft.com/Presspass/press/2009/dec09/12-16Statement.mspx)

Personally I don't want this dialog and the question is how to block it prevent this dialog from being installed through Windows Update

Comment: Turn off Windows Update's automatic updates Don't install the update and untick the box asking for installation later on.

Comment: I've edited this question to keep it on topic for this site and merged it with it's previous version. Keep it on topic or it get's closed.

Comment: Don't vote for "Little Nellie" when you have the choice next time :)

Comment: If you don't want to choose, buy an Apple product.

Answer (score 5):

Most people running IE as default aren't even aware that there is a choice, and wouldn't have a clue how to install another browser (probably wouldn't dare in case it broke their system).

You don't like being forced to **have a choice**?

Assuming this is true, users would only have to make the choice **once**, not every time they start IE.

Even Microsoft's own press-release doesn't make it sound all that bad.

If it really *were* like China, we'd be forced to use a government-provided build of, oh I don't know, *Mosaic*, and there wouldn't **be** a choice.

Answer (score 1):

For a start +1, I am against EU/Microsoft Monopoly statements, Personally, I can install Linux or do what I want on my machine, there is free choice in the marketplace, I choose to use Windows.

I hope that they will release a blocker utility (as they do with some service packs) on [Technet](http://technet.microsoft.com), but if they don't, you will be limited to turning off automatic updates and then manually blocking the update by searching, right clicking and choosing `Hide Update`.

[image]